# Python update string element in 2nd list based on .pop() in 1st list

Tags: python, string, list, loops

I have two lists of strings with numbers. I want to subtract the value of list_1 from list_2, if I do

list_1.pop(0).

```
list_1 = ['4 Green', '3 Blue']
list_2 = ['6 Green', '7 Blue']
```

The new/updated list_2 should look like this:

```
list_2 = ['2 Green', '7 Blue']
```

I already discovered how to subtract these values from each other:

```
rgb = {c: int(n) for n, c in [p.split(' ') for p in list_2]}

for n, c in [p.split(' ') for p in list_1]:
    if c in rgb:
        rgb[c] -= int(n)
    else:
        rgb[c] = -int(n)
print([f'{rgb[p]} {p}' for p in rgb])
```

The challenge now is obvious, I want to implement the .pop function and based on that I want to subtract the values.

Comment: What do you mean by "implement the .pop function"? .pop is a method of a list and it is already implemented, you can just use it.

Comment: I mean to use the .pop method and update list_2 element if correpsonding element in list_1 is deleted